# How to find the total of wins in a tournament?

Tags: probability

Bill and his team are going to compete in a tournament. Bill will
face $N$ team in group stage. Find out how many possible outcomes his team win at least once.

Explanation:
     If $N = 3$

Assume that $W$ is symbol for win and $L$ for lose. Then that means there
     are $7$ out of possible outcomes, in which Bill's team won at least once:

```
     - LLL
     - LLW
     - LWL
     - LWW
     - WLL
     - WLW
     - WWL
     - WWW
```

How do I solve this? Is there any formula that I can use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is binomial experiment.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $A$ be the event that 'Bills team is winning at least one match'. Then the complement event $\bar{A}$ is that 'Bills team doesn't win a single match'.

You may remember the connection of the probability between an event and its complement.

Hope this helped.